# Working with Storage in ZF2

Tags: php, session, zend-framework2

I am using zfcUser and zfcUserLdap to control access to the backoffice of an application.

Now I need to add country selection. I have update the login form and I can get the country selected by the user.

I want to store this country at the storage object, so the backoffice will be working for this country.

This Storage is used on zfcuser and zfcuserldap, but when I want to get the storage from other controller I can't achieve.

At Ldap class in ZfcUserLdap\Authentication\Adapter\ I modified the authenticate method:

```
public function authenticate(AuthEvent $e) {
  ...
    $userObject = $mapper->findByUsername($identity);

    if (null !== $userObject)
    {
        // check the password against the LDAPC directory
        $auth = $mapper->authenticate($userObject->getLdapcObject(), $credential);
        // check if the user belongs to the right LDAPc group
        $hasSecurityGroup = $mapper->hasSecurityGroup($userObject->getLdapcObject());
        if ($auth && $hasSecurityGroup)
        {
            $storage = $this->getStorage()->read();
            $storage['identity'] = $e->getIdentity();
            // set the selected country to manage the backoffice
            **$storage['country'] = $country;**
            $this->getStorage()->write($storage);
            $this->setSatisfied(true);
            $e->setCode(AuthenticationResult::SUCCESS)
                ->setMessages(array('Authentication successful.'))
                ->setIdentity($userObject);

            return;
        }
        else
        {
            $e->setCode(AuthenticationResult::FAILURE_CREDENTIAL_INVALID)
                    ->setMessages(array('Password doesn\'t match'));
            $this->setSatisfied(false);
    ...
    ...
```

This is done while the authentication process.

At the main Index Controller, I want to recover the country selected by the user so I am trying to read the Storage without success

```
...
    try {
        $storage = \ZfcUserLdap\Authentication\Adapter\Ldap::getStorage();
        if ($storage->hasItem('identity'))
            echo $storage->getItem('identity');
        else
            echo 'no esta guardada la identidad';


    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        echo "Caught exception $e\n";
    }
...
```

I am getting the exception:

```
Caught exception exception 'Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException' with message 'Zend\Mvc\Controller\PluginManager::get was unable to fetch or create an instance for setStorage' in /users/p0100/web/vendor/ZF2/library/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php:495
Stack trace:
#0 /users/p0100/web/vendor/ZF2/library/Zend/ServiceManager/AbstractPluginManager.php(103): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->get('setStorage', true)
#1 /users/p0100/web/vendor/ZF2/library/Zend/Mvc/Controller/PluginManager.php(82): Zend\ServiceManager\AbstractPluginManager->get('setStorage', NULL, true)
#2 /users/p0100/web/vendor/ZF2/library/Zend/Mvc/Controller/AbstractController.php(285): Zend\Mvc\Controller\PluginManager->get('setStorage', NULL)
#3 /users/p0100/web/vendor/ZF2/library/Zend/Mvc/Controller/AbstractController.php(300): Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractController->plugin('setStorage')
#4 /users/p0100/web/vendor/ZfcUserLdap/src/ZfcUserLdap/Authentication/Adapter/Ldap.php(116): Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractController->__call('setStorage', Array)
#5 /users/p0100/web/vendor/ZfcUserLdap/src/ZfcUserLdap/Authentication/Adapter/Ldap.php(116): Backoffice\Controller\IndexController->setStorage(Object(Zend\Authentication\Storage\Session))
#6 /users/p0100/web/module/Backoffice/src/Backoffice/Controller/IndexController.php(20): ZfcUserLdap\Authentication\Adapter\Ldap->getStorage()
#7 /users/p0100/web/vendor/ZF2/library/Zend/Mvc/Controller/AbstractActionController.php(83): Backoffice\Controller\IndexController->indexAction()
#8 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#9 /users/p0100/web/vendor/ZF2/library/Zend/EventManager/EventManager.php(468): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#10 /users/p0100/web/vendor/ZF2/library/Zend/EventManager/EventManager.php(207): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#11 /users/p0100/web/vendor/ZF2/library/Zend/Mvc/Controller/AbstractController.php(117): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->trigger('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#12 /users/p0100/web/vendor/ZF2/library/Zend/Mvc/DispatchListener.php(114): Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractController->dispatch(Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Request), Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Response))
#13 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\DispatchListener->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#14 /users/p0100/web/vendor/ZF2/library/Zend/EventManager/EventManager.php(468): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#15 /users/p0100/web/vendor/ZF2/library/Zend/EventManager/EventManager.php(207): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#16 /users/p0100/web/vendor/ZF2/library/Zend/Mvc/Application.php(309): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->trigger('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#17 /users/p0100/web/html/index.php(32): Zend\Mvc\Application->run()
#18 {main}
```

I am far to be a well-known ZF2 developer, what I am doing wrong, please?

- might I create the storage inside the serviceManager?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Line `116` of `ZfcUserLdap/Authentication/Adapter/Ldap.php`. You are calling `$controller->setStorage($object)` however the controller has no such method (or controller plugin) with the name `setStorage()`. Perhaps update you question with that code. There really shouldn't be any reason to do this within the `authenticate` method anyway; You can create you own session containers elsewhere.

Comment: You are right, I was looking at that point too, but I am getting the Storage form Ldap class, so I was trying to figure out why is looking for the method at the controller and not at Ldap class where it is defined. Maybe is because the way I do the assigment that is static to the controller? I will try to create my own session container then .. thanks for the tip!

Comment: I do it at authenticate step because the country selected is also part of the authentication, not every user has access to every country